# Disable TAB navigation in entire application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, focus

How can I disable tab navigation in my WPF application? Or maybe just remove that dotted box around selected items. I know there is:

```
Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"
```

but I can use in specific items, I wish to disable this for entire app.

Comment: app users will detest you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just remove that dotted box around elements, try set [`FocusVisualStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to *`null`*:

```
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
```

Or in Control:

```
<SomeControl FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add the following to the resources of your app.xaml

```
<!-- gets rid of dotted border -->
<Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
</Style>

<!-- turns off tab stops -->
<Style TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
</Style>
```

The question is why would you want to do this for the entire app? Many people use tabbing for navigation, especially people using accessibility software.